# mongodump error connecting to db server in localhost

Tags: mongodb, database

It may be a very simple/obvious answer but I've tried running the following  variations of the same command to backup a local mongo database and they all fail by returning:

**`Failed: error connecting to db server: no reachable servers`**

These are the commands:

- `mongodump --host localhost --port 27017 --db mydbname --collection mycollection`
- `mongodump -h localhost:27017 --db mydbname --collection mycollection -u user -p passw --out <folder path>`
- `mongodump -h localhost:27017 --db mydbname --collection mycollection --out <folder path>`
- `mongodump --port 27017 --db mydbname --collection mycollection --out <folder path>`
- *mongod* instance was running on a separate terminal window while I tried them all

> ```
> I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal 
> I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
> I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=88451 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Diegos-MBP.home
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
> I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.6
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: nogitversion
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Darwin yosemitevm.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Wed Jul 29 02:26:53 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.40.9~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
> I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
> I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
> I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:55910 #1 (1 connection now open)
> ```

I cannot find *mongodb.conf* in `/etc/mongod.conf`. I installed mongo with homebrew. Maybe it is related to an authentication issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue and it appears that using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the host setting worked...

Like :

`mongodump -h 127.0.0.1:27017 -d demo`

If you are using a replicat set (like "myset"), use this instead :

`mongodump -h myset/127.0.0.1:27017 -d demo`

Hope this helps...

Comment: I ran into this issue again, and `mongorestore --host=127.0.0.1 dump` solved it. thank you @Henri

Comment: No problem. It was killing me too and I still have no exact clue why "localhost" wouldn't work.

Comment: Ensure that localhost is really resolved to 127.0.0.1. It can be possible that entry in hosts file is missing. You can check connection to localhost: telnet localhost 27017